# Refresh Captcha , but also refreshing whole register form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Javascript Code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function refreshCaptcha() 
    {
        $("#captchaimage").attr('src','captcha_image.php');
    }
</script>
```

Image Code

```
<img src="captcha_image.php" id="captchaimage">
```

Button Code

```
<button name="submit" class="btnRefresh" onClick="refreshCaptcha();">Refresh Captcha</button>
```

When i tried to click on refresh captcha button , it will refreshed the whole page. Any idea which causing the problem ?

Comment: Your function is missing a closing brace. Either you've poorly snipped your example, or it could even be the cause of the issue

Comment: Please post your form code

Comment: @Red poorly snipped , my bad.

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk added on first thread

Comment: I think your refresh button is interpreted as submit button, try to transform it to an <a> tag. `<a onClick="refreshCaptcha()">refresh img</a>`

Comment: `<a onClick="refreshCaptcha()">refresh img</a>` refresh img unclickable , if i add <button> tag the captcha is not refreshing

Answer (score 2):

`<button>`
by default has the attribute `type="submit"` which causes the form to submit.

Hence, adding `type="button"` to the button will suffice.

Comment: `<button type="button" onClick="refreshCaptcha();">Refresh Captcha</button>` , after this code , my button pressed , but no reaction from my captcha

Comment: a captcha code ( including session ) which work + able to validate , and i found out my refresh ( for refresh captcha , but the code i post above also refreshing the whole form )

Comment: Have you included jQuery link in your code as you seem to use it?

Comment: on which section for jQuery  ?

Comment: In the function `refreshCaptcha()` you select the img by `$("#captchaimage")` which is a jQuery selector. Hence you've to include a link reference to jQuery library in your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `form` has property `action`, button triggers action behavior,then redirecting to action's url.

You can remove `action` or change `button` to `a`,or use `event.preventDefault`.

Comment: remove action still causing the problem , and change to <a> does not work .

Comment: and `<script>
document.getElementById("refreshcaptchabtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
</script>`   the button clicked and no response from it

Comment: My answer is to solve the clicking `button` without triggering `form`.The picture didn't change because his URL didn't change. You could add a random value.This is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/41ghwrmb/1/)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/0a7780d0e57b76fc97873082c594a302 < gif after adding the code , as you can see when i tried to "refresh captcha" the form at the top will get wiped , i need that to prevent the wipe

Comment: It works...[Demo with input added](http://jsfiddle.net/41ghwrmb/14/), Can you show me the complete code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hs4b95od/ , my whole code with captcha thingy + register function , even i remove all my design(css tag) , still error occuring ( same problem)

Comment: 2nd problem if i put the script on below ( after form ) the refresh button will stopped working (click-able, but no action/response).

Comment: You need to put script in the back of form, otherwise Dom(.btnRefresh) will not render the event without registration.[This `button` is working!](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4b95od/2/)

Comment: After implement and change some of my code , the result is that ( After press Refresh Captcha > there is echo :  work ) and my field form is not refreshing ( good sign ) , but my captcha is not changing , is it because my file is unable to add timer on the back causing it unable to refresh ?

Comment: as it because my captcha is on the same file ? i just tested if i refresh my page , on my captcha_image.php date modified will be on that date , after like 1minutes i clicked on refresh captcha button , the image is not updating/refreshing

Comment: Add a parameter `t` with a random value and reload the image by changing the url. If the url does not change, it will not be re-requested. You can directly access the new url to see if the image address is correct.

Comment: not working , i think that my captcha generator only run 1 time when the page is refreshed , and the captcha will never be generated again , is that any ways that able to "re-run/re-generate" the code(php) again ? let say on 4:00pm i refreshed the page ( on folder it will appear 4:00 last modified , but when on 4:02pm i clicked on refresh captcha , on the folder last modified : 4:00pm ) - this is why i think even refreshing is still the same image.

Comment: You need to check the logic for generating captcha.